# Error in Container launch in hadoop on Windows

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a map reduce job on windows and it gives me this error. It specified that there is exception in container launch.

```
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: '/tmp/hadoop-user' is not 
recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


    Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
```

My input in command prompt was : hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.8.2.jar wordcount /user/hadoop/ output
How to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first step is to create a input file, say `/user/data/intestfile.txt`. Then the command should be:

```
$ hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.3.0.jar wordcount /user/data/testfile.txt /temp/output
```

where `$HADOOP_HOME` = environment variable pointing to hadoop installation home. You may replace it with full directory path.

`/test/output` = It is the output location. Make sure that it is accessible and writable. also the output folder should not already exist in `/tmp` folder. The program create it at runtime.

I just executed the command, and it runs fine.

Comment: Can you please share the value of `$HADOOP_HOME`? Can you please try going to the actual directory where the example jar is located -  `$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/` and try executing `hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-xxxx.jar wordcount /user/data/testfile.txt /temp/output`